# When adding a new object the rotation is random

Tags: 3d-view, add-on

When i add a new object `Shift A` in object mode or in edit mode the rotation is zeroed out like it should be but the rotation is random like 
**X=78 Y=31 Z=100**. It always disturbed me like about 3 months and could not find help on the web.

And it happened when i changed accounts on my laptop and started using blender on another account the preferences were reseted, of course, but when i started adding objects the rotation was always random.

Please help!! If I had not told you detailed please tell me what you don't understand, thanks.

As well when adding windows and stuff with the Archimed Add on the rotation as well is random but on the side where is transform, rotation etc... The rotation is zeroed out but in the 3d port view it is rotated in all directions. Please help me and give me some advice to solve this problem/

Thanks,
Anton Pogromskyy

Comment: Check if in the User Preferences > Editing page > New Objects group *Align To* option is not set to *View*. If it is set it to *World*. The last  paragraph from the question isn't quite clear as to what Archimed addon is and when rotation is zeroed out and when not.

Comment: Omg Thanks you SOOOOO much!!! It worked! I had to post this question 3 months ago! Thank you!

Comment: @MrZak please write an answer.

Comment: @cegaton you or anyone else are very welcome to go ahead and write one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open User Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)

In the Editing page go to the New Objects: **Align To:** Option.

Change it from ***View*** to ***World***.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In blender 2.8 you have to set instead of World/View, you have to select the 3D Cursor option.[image]